# R Markdown, creating plots in for loop in different div-tags

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have an R Markdown File with a custom css:

```css
<style>
.superbigimage{
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.superbigimage img{
   max-width: none;
}
</style>
```

This lets me plot a number of plots side by side and in the html i can scroll through the plots. I am wondering if it is possible if i can write plots in a for loop to different tags, so that a new row of plots is created for each iteration of the outer loop.

This would be the code in the code-chunk:

````
<div class="superbigimage">
'```{r bunch-o-figs, echo = FALSE}
  for( i in 1:10 ){
    for(j in 1:10 ){
      plot(...)
    }
    # hear i would need a new div-tag
  }

'```
</div>
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that following solves the issues:

````r
```{r plot_cashflows, results='asis', echo = FALSE}
for( i in 1:10 ){
  cat("<div class=\"superbigimage\">")
  for( j in 1:10 ){
    print(
    plot(...)
    )
  }
  cat("</div>  \n\n")
}

'```
````